# SQL insert into a view

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert information into a view created within my database and its throwing very generic errors.

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' - new error code

```
     INSERT INTO eagle2
            (hotelname,
             hotelcity,
             hotelpostcode)
VALUES      ('EaglePalace',
             'Sydney',
             '2000')

INSERT INTO eagle2
            (hotelname,
             hotelcity,
             hotelpostcode)
VALUES      ('EagleRegis',
             'Perth',
             '6000')
```

Both of these both separate and together aren't working, and I know its probably so simple but I've wasted 2 hours on this already.

I have a view that I created already called eagle2 and now just want to insert the two new rows.

[image: eagles2]

Comment: You cannot insert value into a view.It is just a virtual table.

Comment: This is part of my diploma, its one of the units.. Is the unit actually wrong?

Comment: You cannot insert data into a view. Instead you must insert the data into the table(s) on which the view is built.

Comment: Go through this article.You will get an idea about views in database. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: @Karthikeyan: that is not true. In all modern DBMS you _can_ insert into view. Simple ones (no joins, no aggregates) are usually "auto-insertable". More complicated ones require an instead of trigger to make that work.

Comment: The error message is clear: you are inserting a row with a value for the primary key that already exists. But without the table definition this is impossible to answer. You also might want to read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: The error message was a new one I made because I changed something, its irrelevant as I changed it back to the way it should be and set the PK to be auto incrementing again.

Comment: So there is another column you forgot to tell us about - an ID column you were not updating.  Next time I suggest posting more information - makes  HUGE difference in the speed of answers, and you won't get the mark-downs to your reputation.    All makes sense now.  Glad you worked it out - make sure you close off this.

Comment: @Karthikeyan, @Patrick, try this: `create table t (c int); create view v as select c from t; insert into v values (123); select * from t;`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what SQL server you are using.  Not all servers support updating data via views.

If you ARE using a database where it is possible, then you should know that not all views CAN be updated.  It depends if the database can work out what record it should change, or not.

So a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW test AS select a, b, c from Foo where filtercol=2
```

Could be updated but a view with complicated joins and the like could not -  Because the database cannot work out what records in the source tables need changing.

EDIT:  I forgot to add that with some databases you can define a trigger that fires on a complicated view that tells the database what to do instead for the insert/update/delete operations (Postgres allows an "instead of" trigger to support this)

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin, sorry I forget there are alternatives, I'm only new to all of this. Its a view created literally from one single table, but I'm still getting the same error even trying to insert into the original table.

Comment: Okay you are using MySQL which I know does support these.  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 5.0.12? I think. Its the latest one as of a couple weeks ago, I just downloaded it again to local host it on my laptop.

Comment: I am not an expert in the current MySQL.  I know in the past some features depending on the data store selected.  However we still haven't seen your view definition.  Please add that to your question.  My guess from the error that the logic in the view is causing the issue - but it is a guess unless we can see the view.